# Freeing stuck objects after collision

Tags: c#, collision-detection, game-engine, collision

I have run into a slight issue with the collision resolution in my game engine.  If two objects collide and that collision causes the velocity to go to zero, the edges of the objects will overlap each other and they'll be stuck.

Is there a way to implement a catchall for this kind of a situation? i.e. move the objects just enough in the right direction so they are not stuck.

Here is how I am checking collisions and moving objects.  When update is called on an entity, it moves the (x,y).

```
    public static void Update()
        {
            for (var iterator = 0; iterator < PhysicsEntities.Count; iterator++)
            {
                for (var index = iterator + 1; index < PhysicsEntities.Count; index++)
                {
                    if (!Collision.ResolveCollision(PhysicsEntities[iterator],
                         PhysicsEntities[index], Detection)) continue;
                    PhysicsEntities[iterator].Update();
                    PhysicsEntities[iterator].Collided = true;
                    PhysicsEntities[index].Update();
                    PhysicsEntities[index].Collided = true;
                }
            }

            foreach (var entity in PhysicsEntities)
            {
                entity.Update(velocity: true);
                entity.Collided = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the update function for the entities:

```
public void Update(bool velocity = false)
    {
        if(!Movable) return;
        if (!Collided)
        {
            var moveX = Velocity.X / Universe.UpdateInterval;
            var moveY = Velocity.Y / Universe.UpdateInterval;
            Position.Move(moveX, moveY);
            BoundingBox.Move(moveX, moveY);
        }
        if(velocity) UniversalForces();
    }

    private void UniversalForces()
    {
        Velocity.Scale(1 - Universe.Friction);
        Velocity.Add(Universe.GravityMag, Universe.GravityDir);
    }
```

Finally, here is a image of one simulation where the objects get stuck.  As you can see, it is just the edges that are getting stuck:

[image]

Comment: Look before you leap! :) Compute a test iteration of the entire set moving, look for collisions, and then go back and handle which pieces of the set interacted by either slowing them down, path finding them at speed into each other, or by some other metric to avoid crossing boundaries.

Comment: To be fair, even new games like Rocket League still suffer from having their ball overlap with the cars and getting that weird shaking effect. The ball in town for Destiny is even worse. So, this isn't exactly something that is easily solved.

Comment: I changed my code a bit so if an object collides, it does not move, just the other object if it is movable, but the movement looks rigid and very unrealistic.  The overlapping does not happen, but things don't collide correctly either.

Comment: If any collide, rewind, then draw a line from the center of both balls, and move them along that line until they touch using their compared speed to generate the ratio of how far they should go.

Comment: I have a whole class dedicated to doing per pixel collision, and it calculates the correct magnitude and direction for each object.  I think it works now that I deleted `PhysicsEntities[iterator].Update();` and `PhysicsEntities[index].Collided = true;` but I have no clue why it works.

Comment: UPDATE: it does not work really, it just breaks less often.

Comment: This is a pet project to understand more about physics and how a game engine works.

Comment: The main problem with your approach (and approaches in general - there are a lot that do this) is that in the real world objects don't move iteratively; they all move at the same time.

Comment: @TravisJ that is a very good observation sir.  So striving for perfection is not possible with this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick solution is to move both objects back to the previous tic's position and any other object that causes a collision with to move back as well.  It works, but it looks messy and causes some behavior that looks really bad - things like pushing directly at a wall leaves a gap, but angling towards a wall leaves a smaller gap.  Very messy.

The better solution is to move both objects back just far enough along their negative velocity vector so that they are no longer touching.  Usually some dot product math can give you what you need for this, though iterating backwards can work (slow).

Long story short, don't ever allow objects to overlap.  Take care of it before it happens and you avoid stuck jitters, can't move stuff, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When one object collides with another, get it to backtrack up its own movement vector so that the distance between the centroids of both objects is equal to the two radius. This works if its a circle - if its a complex polygon you really need to do edge collision detection instead of bounding sphere detection. If the bounding spheres collide, then you move to complex edge detection. In the end the trick is the same; check for collision then back up the movement vector until you find the exact (or nearly exact) point of collision.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out with the suggestions people made.  Some of the changes I made include having each object collide with any other object only once per update, and moving the object after the collision until it is no longer colliding.  Here is the code that I used to do that, feel free to use this on any project and let me know if you have any questions about it.

```
public static void Update()
    {
        foreach (var a in PhysicsEntities)
        {
            foreach (var b in PhysicsEntities)
            {
                if (a.Equals(b) || 
                    !Collision.ResolveCollision(a, b, Detection) || b.Collided) continue;

                while (Detection == Detection.BoundingBox ? 
                           Collision.BoundingBox(a, b) : 
                           Collision.PixelPerfect(a, b))
                {
                    const float moveBy = .5F;
                    var moveX = a.Position.X > b.Position.X ? moveBy : -moveBy;
                    var moveY = a.Position.Y > b.Position.Y ? moveBy : -moveBy;

                    if (a.Movable)
                    {
                        a.Move(moveX, moveY);
                        a.Velocity.Scale(-1);
                    }
                    else if (b.Movable)
                    {
                        b.Move(moveX * -1, moveY * -1);
                        b.Velocity.Scale(-1);
                    }
                }

                a.Update();
                b.Update();
                a.Collided = a.Movable;
            }
        }

        foreach (var entity in PhysicsEntities)
        {
            entity.Update(velocity: true);
            entity.Collided = false;
        }
    }
```